# jquery animate queue

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I have some span tags:

```
<span data-w="560"></span>
<span data-w="340"></span>
<span data-w="120"></span>
```

I have a jQuery code to animate each span to reach a target width preset inthe data-w attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('span').each(function() {

        $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('data-w') + 'px'}, 1000);

    });

});
```

here everything works just fine.

Now I want to make each span animate alone, and not all of the spans together.

How to do it? may be with queue()? how?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/AqgbG/

Comment: on jsfiddle it works but for on my app it doesn't. I really don't know why as the only difference is the ++i *

Comment: Note that `i` is the index, you should pass it to the function as I did in the fiddle.

Comment: ok it works now but it's not the specific effect that I want, beacause, my app is a poll system that reorders results based on the the percentage of votes, so the first will be the greatest percentage and so on. with your idea, it will not animate one by one, they will all start together but the speed will decrease so the following will be slower then the precedent, and because the following is always smaller and shorter, it must NOT be slower, just concentrate on the jsfiddle example and you will get the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayby you can create your own queue:

```
var spanW_loop = 0;
var spanW_size = jQuery('#spanW span[data-w]').length;

    function animateSpanW() {
    var spanWidth = jQuery('#spanW').children('span[data-w]').eq(spanW_loop).attr('data-w');
        jQuery('#spanW').children('span[data-w]').eq(spanW_loop).animate({width: spanWidth + 'px'}, 1000, function() {
            spanW_loop += 1;
            if(spanW_loop < spanW_size) {
                animateSpanW();
            }
        });
    }

animateSpanW();
```

​